# How to move all files in a folder at a ftp server to another folder in the same ftp server

Tags: ftp, dos

How to move all files in a folder at a ftp server to another folder in the same ftp server.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the raw ftp commands rnfr and rnto.
rnfr chooses the file to rename from. After receiving a confirmation you can use rnto to store it under a different filename.
this works also with directories. You will have to be at a parent directory in order to that that and create to directory to move to as well, for example:

to move /rootFolder/1 to /rootFolder/2 :

```
CWD /rootFolder
MKD 2
RNFR 1
RNTO 2
```

Comment: Thanks Raanan. I guess this will work good for a specific file or an specific folder. But actually i want to move all files in an folder(i do not know their names) into an archive folder in the same ftp server.Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Well, this will move all files in folder "1" to folder "2" . I am not quite sure what the difference is, can you give me an example of the folder names and locations you wish to move?

Comment: I have a set of files in a folder called "Input".I need to move all the files in "Input" folder to "Archive" folder.Both these folders are in FTP Server only.

Comment: so this is exactly what you need to use... go to their root folder, and run RNFR Input [ENTER] - wait for confirmation, and then write RNFR Archive [ENTER] . this will mvoe all files and subdictories in Input to Archive.  If you need to move more than one directory to Archive, or you want the Input directory to move to Archive in its whole, create a subdirctory in Archive, called Input, and then, after the RNFR command, run RNTO Archive/Input