# How to move files in the FTP server

Tags: powershell, ftp, file-rename, ftpwebrequest

I want move files from a FTP server to another directory in the same server. I think the method that I have to use is `Rename`. Well, I can't continue because i don't know how. In put or get operations there are data stream but not here, that's my problem

```
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($Source)
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)  
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::Rename   
$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move all files in a folder at a ftp server to another folder in the same ftp server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759626/how-to-move-all-files-in-a-folder-at-a-ftp-server-to-another-folder-in-the-same)

Comment: @alondono If the op is willing to accept an out of language solution maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FtpWebRequest.RenameTo` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.renameto) to specify the target name (path):

```
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::Rename   
$ftprequest.RenameTo = "/another/directory/filename.ext"
$ftprequest.GetResponse().Dispose()
```

Note that you do not need the result of the `GetResponse()` method.